# PHPExcel : optimal range cell with highest cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to export an excel array with optimal format.
So I search the highest cell :

```
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); 

$highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();

$highestcell=($highestColumn.$highestRow);
```

And now I want to applicate the style to the range of cells `(A2:$highestCell)`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:$highestcell')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
```

The problem is that getStyle is only for one cell or a range of cells (A1:B1) for example.
So how can I resolve my problem to have an optimal format for my Excel sheet.

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.
Corentin

Edit : I found the solution, just getStyle('A2:'$highestcell)

Comment: If you can explain what you mean by an "optimal format", then it might be easier to answer your question

Comment: I just mean that i want the bordures stop at the last row which is written.

Comment: What borders? Do you really want to set a view area instead?

Comment: What is a view area ?                                                                                    My problem is that i export data in excel and i don't have always the same datas number. So for the moment i just put an constant range cell to applicate the style, and I would have a flexible range cell.

Comment: Well surely defining a range like `A2:$highestCell` is flexible?

Comment: Yes exactly, actually $highestCell will not have the same value for each export i will do, it's what I call flexible.